# Assistance writing jQuery code to hide elements on webpage?

Tags: jquery

I'm job searching on indeed.com and would like to run jquery code to hide all sponsored listings as they continue to repeat from page to page. I need assistance in writing code to run in the console to accomplish this goal.

Indeed.com uses jQuery, but I'm not sure how to get it to run as jQuery is undefined.

Here is example code of what hopefully provides an indication of what I'm trying to do.

```
$('.sponsoredGray').parent().hide();
```

When running the code in the console, I expect a search for all spans with the class of 'sponsoredGray', which then will traverse back up the DOM to find the class of 'jobsearch-SerpJobCard' and hide the container.

Here is a screenshot as it might be helpful.

[image]

Comment: @akaBase He's trying to filter what it shows to him.

Comment: @akaBase That won't work, you need a loop to add the style to all the matching elements.

Comment: Like Barmar said, I'm trying to filter the search results. Every day I spend a couple of hours searching through lists of jobs and the same sponsored jobs appear on every page. If I can just hide these listings, I could save a lot of time, which I could use applying for jobs instead of search for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the equivalent plain JavaScript:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".jobsearch-SerpJobCard .sponsoredGray").forEach(el => {
    el.closest('.jobsearch-SerpJobCard').style.display = 'none';
});
```

Comment: This doesn't hide the container, just the span that you cannot see anyway. This is on the right track though.

Comment: This is equivalent to the jQuery code that you posted in the question. If that's not correct, it's not my fault.

Comment: I've updated it to search for the containing element with the class you mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thanks Barmar but I get the error shown in screenshot.

https://www.screencast.com/t/zkcUCai2utJr

Comment: Oops, forgot the style to assign to

Comment: Edit the question and show the HTML. You're obviously not describing it correctly.

Comment: Maybe there are some `sponsoredGray` elements that aren't inside cards. I've added a conditional.

Comment: I changed the selector to only match sponsored elements that are inside cards.

Comment: thank you so very much. This appears to work perfectly. This will save me a lot of time searching.